# aws s3 ls --summarize switch is broken when trying to get the size of a specific prefix in a bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Am I stupid or is this command just totally broken or unclear in usage

I want to see the size of a specific prefix in a bucket

```
aws s3 ls --summarize --human-readable --recursive 's3://mybucket/myfolder/'
```

OR

```
aws s3 ls 's3://mybucket/myfolder/' --summarize --human-readable --recursive
```

This returns every individual object with a prefix of `myfolder/`- how is that a summary of anything? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The `--summarize` flag prints out the summary (total objects and total size) at the end of the output. If you only want to see the summary, use `tail`:

```
aws s3 ls --summarize --recursive 's3://mybucket/myfolder/ | tail -2'
```